# Is there a bug at the election page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, election

I went into the election page to vote for the 2013 Community Moderators election (Primary).

But when I clicked into @green7's vote, it went strange:

[image: The original @green7 vote with -1] 
turned into
[image: The new @green7 vote with +8 and -15.]

8-15 = -7. How could this be -1?

It seems that for almost every candidate I voted DOWN on it would show a -1 instead of it's total vote number. Can anyone fix that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It never goes below `-1` (well, except when you add a downvote, but that clears out on refreshing)

See [Election primary vote count is no lower than -1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135576/election-primary-vote-count-is-no-lower-than-1/135577#135577)

> It was decided to be too cruel to display a person as having a score less than 0.